# TypeError: Cannot read property 'alertIsPresent' of undefined

Tags: protractor

If i use

```js
var Alerts = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 1000);
```

i am getting error like below

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'alertIsPresent' of undefined
```

Please help me how to wait till alert is present without `browser.sleep();`

Answer (score 0):

```
Const EC =require('protractor').ExpectedConditions;  
browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 5000);
```

[Protractor documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.alertIsPresent)